# Can Flyway backup and restore data where necessary for migrations using ALTER TABLE?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, database-migration, flyway

How does Flyway handle column ALTERs where row data cannot be migrated in place and must be truncated; **does Flyway handle backup and restoration of data in such cases**?

Found this in [Flyway's documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#downgrade), the recommendation for doing data backup/restore is leveraging the databases' own tools. This is fine, but I can't tell if Flyway also has its own feature for doing the same, even if it's inferior to native RDBMS capabilities.

> ..but I'm For optimal performance, and if your infrastructure supports
>   this, we recommend using the snapshot technology of your underlying
>   storage solution. Especially for larger data volumes, this can be
>   several orders of magnitude faster than traditional backups and
>   restores!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Flyway does what you tell it to do. Nothing less. Nothing more.